# How to sync offline local database with server when getting internet connection in swift not objective c?

Tags: ios, swift

Actually I want save the data offline and when internet connection on api will be hitting. if app is close then also api hit

```
func proileApi(){


    // AMShimmer.start(for: view)
    AMShimmer.start(for: profileView)

    SVProgressHUD.show()
    let todoSubmitJob: String = "https://www.api.com?epID=\(storeUserId!)"
    print("the submitValue is ",todoSubmitJob)
    Alamofire.request(todoSubmitJob).responseJSON { response in
        // check for errors
        guard response.result.error == nil else {
            // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
            print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
            print(response.result.error!)
            let error  = response.result.error!.localizedDescription
            self.displayAlertMessage(messageToDisplay: error)
            return
        }

        AMShimmer.stop(for: self.profileView)
         SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        // make sure we got some JSON since that's what we expect
        let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any]
       // print("theloginAuthValue is ",json!)
        let responseStatus = json!["responseStatus"] as! Bool
        if (responseStatus == true){
            let responseData = json!["responseData"] as! [Any]
            var index = 0
            while index < responseData.count{
                let responseArray = responseData[index] as! [String: Any]
                let id = responseArray["$id"] as! String
                let accountNumber = responseArray["ACNo"] as! String
                let bankID = responseArray["BankID"] as! Int
                let branch = responseArray["Branch"] as! String
                let dateOfBirth = responseArray["DateOfBirth"] as! String
                let dateOfJoining = responseArray["DateOfJoining"] as! String
                let departmentID = responseArray["DepartmentID"] as! String
                let deptRoleId = responseArray["DeptRoleId"] as! Int
                let designationID = responseArray["DesignationID"] as! String
                let empCode = responseArray["EmpCode"] as! String
                let emailID = responseArray["EmailID"] as! String
                let employmentType = responseArray["EmploymentType"] as! String
                let firstName = responseArray["FirstName"] as! String
                let functionName = responseArray["FunctionName"] as! String
                let guardianName = responseArray["GuardianName"] as! String
                let lastName = responseArray["LastName"] as! String
                let maritalStatus = responseArray["MaritalStatus"] as! String
                let mobile = responseArray["Mobile"] as! String
                let permanentAddress = responseArray["PermanentAddress"] as! String
                let permanentCityID = responseArray ["PermanentCityID"] as! String
                let permanentCountryID = responseArray["PermanentCountryID"] as! String
                let permanentPinCode = responseArray["PermanentPinCode"] as! String
                let permanentStateID = responseArray["PermanentStateID"] as! String
                let personalEmail = responseArray ["PersonalEmail"] as! String
                let presentAddress = responseArray["PresentAddress"] as! String
                let presentCityID = responseArray["PresentCityID"] as! String
                let presentCountryID = responseArray["PresentCountryID"] as! String
                let presentPincode = responseArray["PresentPincode"] as! String
                let PresentStateID = responseArray["PresentStateID"] as! String
                let sex = responseArray["Sex"] as! String

                let lstFamily = responseArray["lstFamily"] as![Any]
                var index2 = 0
                while index2 < lstFamily.count{
                    let responseSubArray = lstFamily[index2] as! [String: Any]
                    let rltnName = responseSubArray["RltnName"] as! String
                    let memberID = responseSubArray["MemberID"] as! Int
                    let memberName = responseSubArray["MemberName"] as! String

                    UserDefaults.standard.set(lstFamily, forKey: "lstFamily")




                     print("myLove:",rltnName)
                    index2 += 1

                }



                self.firstNameValue.text = firstName
                self.lastNameValue.text = lastName
                self.branchNameValue.text = branch
                self.depatmentValue.text = departmentID
                self.funtionValue.text = functionName
                self.designationValue.text = designationID
                self.dateOfJoinigValue.text = dateOfJoining
                self.EmploymentValue.text = employmentType



                 index += 1


            }

        }
        else if (responseStatus == false){

            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            self.displayIndicatorAlert(message: "Somthing wrong.Please try again")

        }

    }


}
```

In this code I fetch the value . I want to know if offline some one button press and close the application . After that if internet connection on application api hitting without application open .

Comment: You can try Magical Record pod 
https://cocoapods.org/pods/MagicalRecord

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to synchronize coredata with webservices in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888703/how-to-synchronize-coredata-with-webservices-in-swift)

Comment: The code are in objective c and I don know . Can you please explain this or can  you provide some source code